# Sumproduct between row and column with condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In the following sheet, the sumproduct of a row with a column (which has a condition) is 2. Why 2? I've read through the [sumproduct](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en-GB) docs, and it's not clear to me what happens in a situation like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the value of each column is added to the value of each row and the result is an array:

```
5,6,7
6,7,8
7,8,9
```

which is compared to `6` and results in an array:

```
0,1,0
1,0,0
0,0,0
```